# Transforming a function into a list in Drracket

Tags: scheme, racket

I create a function which create list. I want to use that list in an another function so how can I do this?

```scm
(define (myfunc L n) 
  (if (= n 0)
      empty 
      (cons (list-ref L (random 26)) 
            (myfunc L (- n 1)))))
```

I want to assing this function as a list to make it useful for using in an another function.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already. Also, have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit your original question with this information. It's hard to understand what you mean by just reading the comment.

Comment: It sounds like you would just call the function and use the list it returns. I don't see how "transforming" a function into a list would get you something useful.

Comment: yes, I've exactly meant that. I'm sorry about my insufficient english. so how can I do that?

Comment: You actually call the function in your code on the last line: `(myfunc L (- n 1))`. Calling it from top level `define` or from another function works the same way. If it's not obvious  you need to update your question with what you are actually trying to do with `myfunc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your definition:

```
(define (myfunc L n)
  (if (= n 0)
      empty
      (cons (list-ref L (random 26))
            (myfunc L (- n 1)))))
```

### Functions that take Functions

Because Schemes treat functions as first class values, `myfunc` can be passed as a function to another function. We can write a second function that accepts a function as an argument:

```
(define (another-function a-function L n)
  (print "another-function: ")
  (a-function L n))            ; call a-function just like a built in function
```

We can pass `myfunc` into `another-function`. Then `my-func` will be called within `another-function`:

```
racket> (another-function myfunc (range 40) 4)
"another-function: "'(0 9 13 2)
```

This shows how functions are passed as arguments. The important idea is Scheme passes functions as functions not as lists. Scheme passes functions as values not as source code that will be evaluated to a value.

### Functions Returning Functions

To drive home the idea that functions are values, we look at functions that return functions. Here is a function that returns a function like `myfunc` except that we can use a different value instead of `26`:

```
(define (make-myfunc r)
  (define (inner-myfunc L n)              ; define a new function like myfunc
    (if (= n 0)
        empty
        (cons (list-ref L (random r))     ; use r instead of 26
              (inner-myfunc L (- n 1)))))
  inner-myfunc)                           ; return the new function
```

We can use it like this:

```
racket> (define myfunc4 (make-myfunc 4))
racket> (myfunc4 (range 40) 4)
'(2 0 3 0)
```

#### Functions that take functions and return functions

Here is a function that takes one function and returns a different function:

```
(define (make-another-function a-function)
  ;; because the function we are returning does not call 
  ;; itself recursively, we can use lambda instead of define.
  (lambda (L n)                                
    (print "made by make-another-function: ")
    (a-function L n)))
```

And here it is in use:

```
racket> (define yet-another-function (make-another-function myfunc))
racket> (yet-another-function (range 40) 3)
"made by make-another-function: "'(1 18 16)
```